# Debian /etc/init.d/ script not running?

Tags: java, linux, debian, beagleboneblack

I'm using a BeagleBone Black that runs Debian (the latest version that the BeagleBone website provides a link for, I believe) and I recently installed Java on it. Every time I boot the board I must set the PATH for Java again as shown below.

```
root@beaglebone:/etc/init.d# java -version
-bash: java: command not found
root@beaglebone:/etc/init.d# export PATH=$PATH:/bin/jdk1.7.0_60/bin
root@beaglebone:/etc/init.d# export JAVA_HOME=/bin/jdk1.7.0_60
root@beaglebone:/etc/init.d# java -version
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
root@beaglebone:/etc/init.d#
```

I wanted to write a script to set up java during start-up and then run some java program. So I wrote a script "helium_startup.sh" and put it in init.d, the script looks like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/bin/jdk1.7.0_60/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/bin/jdk1.7.0_60
```

I haven't wrote the program that I would like to run here yet, but I think I could place a line to run it right after these two lines, right? Then I use update-rc.d to create the links:

```
root@beaglebone:/etc/init.d# update-rc.d helium_startup.sh defaults
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
insserv: warning: script 'helium_startup.sh' missing LSB tags and overrides
```

I believe that the warning doesn't affect anything? I checked /etc/rc5.d to verify that one of the links was made:

```
root@beaglebone:~# cd /etc/rc5.d
root@beaglebone:/etc/rc5.d# ls
README              S01sudo               S03loadcpufreq   S04wicd
S01boot_scripts.sh  S01xrdp               S03rsync         S05saned
S01bootlogs         S02apache2            S03ssh           S06rc.local
S01capemgr.sh       S03acpid              S03udhcpd        S06rmnologin
S01hostapd          S03cron               S04avahi-daemon
S01motd             S03dbus               S04cpufrequtils
S01rsyslog          S03helium_startup.sh  S04lightdm
```

And, the links do appear to be made for each of the run levels. Then I reboot the Beaglebone (I've tried doing it by "reboot", unplugging it, and pressing power button) and attempt to check the version of java:

```
root@beaglebone:/etc/rc5.d# java -version
-bash: java: command not found
```

And it fails. I'm new to Debian (and Linux in general) and this is my first time using the BeagleBone Black, I'm not sure what the issue is. I also tried putting the 2 lines to set the PATH for java in /etc/rc.local, and that didn't work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-Brandon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set an environment variable (PATH) permanently in an init script. The appropriate place would be a script in `/etc/profile.d`