# running shell script during boot

Tags: beagleboneblack

i have a shell script which i require to run during boot
 i have followed the link

[Executing a script on startup using BeagleBone Black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854705/executing-a-script-on-startup-using-beaglebone-black)

by this, the service is getting created but when i check by using systemctl,
it is showing failed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wWVe.jpg)

can anyone help me

Comment: try to avoid adding images instead of data in questions.

Comment: Please include the output of `systemctl status startup1.service`.

Comment: startup1.service - startup1
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/startup1.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2018-01-28 14:16:59 UTC; 8min ago
 Main PID: 1139 (startup1.sh)
    Tasks: 5 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/startup1.service
           ├─1139 /bin/sh /usr/bin/startup1.sh
           ├─1327 /bin/sh /home/debian/bin/HLC/runscript_text_display_1.08.sh
           ├─1373 /bin/sh /home/debian/bin/HLC/init.sh
           ├─1400 /bin/bash /home/debian/bin/HLC/write_rtc_time.sh
           └─3272 /home/debian/bin/HLC/send_data_to_lcd.o

Comment: I meant to include it in the question, iow edit the question. By the limited information I can glean it actually looks like it's running just fine.

Comment: i am not undertanding the same..i could see active running..but my script is starting and getting failed in less than 10 sec

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue last days. Your problem is related to the "Type" field in "[Service]" part. Your are using Type=simple which execute at the beginning without wait for the other resource necessary to use your script. By changing to Type=idle should solve the problem.

**idle** means that your script will execute after all the service are initiated.

A better approach is by looking the services that your script needs, and also writing the field "After=service_required_by_my_script.service service2_required_by_my_script.service ...and more" in the [Service] part.

Recommended literature:

- [Arch linux Wiki Systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd) (look in "Service types")
- [Getting Started With systemd on Debian Jessie](http://Getting%20Started%20With%20systemd%20on%20Debian%20Jessie)

Similar problem:

- [Beaglebone Debian/jessie autoinit script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425701/beaglebone-debian-jessie-autoinit-script)